# Google maps: API 3, how to set polyline in the center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, center, polyline

Hi all I need to be able to center the polyline in the center of the map

Only the necessery part of the code...

```
success: function(data) {//callback to be executed when the response has been received

    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].x,data[i].y);
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_find"),
    mapOptions);
    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates,
            strokeColor: "#8a2be2",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
    map.setZoom(5);
    map.setCenter(flightPlanCoordinates);
}
```

This is not doing what I need..My map is not centered and not zoomed, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use this function, calling it with the polyline as parameter:

```
function zoomToObject(obj){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var points = obj.getPath().getArray();
    for (var n = 0; n < points.length ; n++){
        bounds.extend(points[n]);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Call it:

```
flightPath.setMap(map);
zoomToObject(flightPath);
```

Just make sure that your map object is a global variable.

Comment: I need to call it before this line `flightPath.setMap(map);` ?

Comment: I think that your code is working, but know my map is not initialized in the whole div...it is like in the 1/6 of the entire div when I call this function. Any idea?

Comment: It's probably best if you post a new question with full code. Does your map <div> have a size? (both width and height)?

Comment: I have post a new question, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032245/google-polyline-is-not-in-the-center-and-not-zoomed